# Manage video stream in HTML5

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, streaming

I creted this web page:

```
<html>
<title>WebCam stream</title>
<body>
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
width="640"
height="480"
id="vlc">
</embed>
<script language="Javascript">
var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
vlc.playlist.add("http://myIpAddress:11345");
vlc.playlist.play();
vlc.audio.toggleMute();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine in Chrome or Mozilla, but I need to use Internet Explorer and for this my page does not work.

I also tried to use HTML 5 video support in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head><title>webCamStream</title></head>

<body>
<video controls preload autoplay>  
    <source src="http://95.225.xx.yy:11345" type="video/mp4; 'codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'" />  
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

But Explorer does not work.

Can I modify the

> type="video/mp4; 'codecs='avc1.42E01E

In order to manager a ASF video format? What codecs I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Internet Explorer are you trying this on, you don't say. I assume it's 9 or 10, as anything less than that does not support HTML5 video.

Try removing the codec from the `type` attribute, simply setting it to `"video/mp4"`.